# Tweaking gets() to avoid buffer overflow

Tags: c, string, malloc, fgets, gets

I am writing a small C code to take some user input, which would be a string. Now I read at a lot of places that using gets() will be very unsafe as it may lead to buffer overflow attacks. And in most of the places what I found as an alternative was using fgets() instead, which is safer as far as buffer overflows are concerned.

Now I have a problem scenario, where in I do not know the buffer size before hand. It just can not be determined. It could be anything. So in this case, will fgets() be handy ?

Also, what is wrong if I make use of gets(), as shown below, to solve this problem ?

```
char * temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input = NULL;
cahr * actual_buffer_that_stores_user_input = NULL;
int length_of_user_input =0;

/* taking user input, irrespective of its length using gets() */

gets(temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input);

/* now finding the length of the user input string and allocating the required number of bytes for proper (safe) usage */

length_of_user_input=length(temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input);
actual_buffer_that_stores_user_input = (char*)malloc(length_of_user_input*sizeof(char));
strcpy(actual_buffer_that_stores_user_input, temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input);

/* and now we work with our actual buffer */
```

So does the above usage of gets() still have buffer overflow problem ? Because, in the above we are not declaring a fixed size buffer at all in the first place... so no buffer overflow is what I am expecting.

Please correct me if I am missing out on something!

Comment: Indeed there is no buffer overflow. `gets()` storing the string at `NULL` will hurt though.

Comment: Just say **NO** to `gets()` and get on with your life. Just FYI: `gets()` is no longer part of the C language since December 2011 (some C2011 compilers provide it as an extension; other compilers may not be C2011 compatible yet).

Comment: No buffer overflow problem will occur, because you using dynamic array(char * temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input = NULL;). And i think there is no need for storing the i/p to another array.

Comment: On POSIX platforms, use `getline` or `getdelim` instead.

Comment: You can simulate getline by: 1. fgetc until your buffer is filled/newline-reached or 2. fread() to a buffer and strcspn() to find out where your newline is (then handle moving extra data or seeking).

Answer (score 5):

```
char * temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input = NULL;
```

You set the pointer to `NULL`.  Hence there is *no buffer at all* and `gets` will fail with undefined behavior (probably a segmentation fault in practice).

`gets` requires that you present a valid pointer to a buffer.  A null pointer doesn't point to anything, hence this pre-condition is not satisfied.  Since all buffers have finite length and user input is of unknown length, there's just no way at all to avoid getting a potential buffer overflow (and not to mention security risk).  It's so bad that `gets` has been **removed from the official standard**.

The correct way is to use `fgets`.  Dealing with a variable-sized input is tricky though, so you have two options:

- Use `fgets` with a "large-enough for all my cases" buffer size.  The easy way out.  Worst case is you lose some input.
- Repeatedly use `fgets` and concatenate to some dynamically allocated array (and don't forget to resize this array as needed!) until you reach the delimiter.  *Note:* depending on what you're doing with the string though, you may not even need to hold the entire thing around, which simplifies things.

Comment: I agree. What you could do in practice is call "fgets" repeatetly using a finite length temp_buffer_to_hold_user_input until the buffer you are reading from is empty, and each time increase the size of your  actual_buffer_that_stores_user_input and append the new data.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the buffer size before hand you can take a look to [getline()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html), or build your own function and `realloc` your string, something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buf[8], *s = NULL, *p;
    size_t i = 0;

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
        if (i++ == 0) {
            s = malloc(sizeof buf);
            if (s == NULL) {
                perror("malloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcpy(s, buf);
        } else {
            s = realloc(s, (i + 1) * sizeof(buf));
            if (s == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            strcat(s, buf);
        }
        if ((p = strchr(s, '\n'))) {
            *p = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Without an intermediate buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_LEN 8

int main(void)
{
    size_t len = BUF_LEN;
    char *s, *p;

    p = s = malloc(len);
    if (s == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (fgets(p, BUF_LEN, stdin)) {
        if ((p = strchr(p, '\n'))) {
            *p = '\0';
            break;
        } else {
            len += BUF_LEN - 1;
            s = realloc(s, len);
            if (s == NULL) {
                perror("realloc");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            p = s + len - BUF_LEN;
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love the warning about always checking the result of `malloc` and `realloc` below the sample code that doesn't. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MagrittePipe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

> Tweaking gets() to avoid buffer overflow

Others have addressed your questions in the body. Here's a quick answer that addresses the question in your title.

Standard C provides a "safer" variant of `gets` via `gets_s`. Its was added to the C Standard with [ISO/IEC TR 24731-1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1225.pdf). Among other things, the safer function of TR 24731-1 check the destination buffer size to avoid many of the buffer overflow problems of their "unsafe" counterparts.

Here's from the document:

[image]

So you really don't need to tweak anything. You only need to use the correct function for the job ;)